# Getting total count in each grid cell from multiple point and polygon layers using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-join, vector-grid, count

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

The multiple point and polygon feature layers are sources of a toxic chemical but from different companies/studies/departments, etc. The grid layer was created with the Grid Feature Index tool, so the grids are polygons.

I tried to Batch Summary Within, Batch Spatial Join, but it is not working. The 'Join_Count' field of the Spatial Join result is only counting the last feature listed in the batch. The 'Count of Points' field for Summarize Within is doing the same thing.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are your point\polygon datasets multi-part? If so explode them to single part first?